# Refresh data called by controller every 5 seconds MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need my controller to get new data every 5 seconds by calling a function which loads a file hard coded (for the moment)

Here's my code:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
            waitHandle,

            (state, timeout) =>
            {
                InfoXML.LoadXml();
            },
            null,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            false
        );
        return View();
    }
}
```

}

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: It will be helpful if you can add details on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I said it no? I'm trying to make my controller get data every 5 seconds. I think SignalR is the solution